# Power App Administrator modules not working when using Service Principal login

Tags: powershell, powerapps, power-platform

I am trying to build a pipeline to automate my power app solution deployment from azure devOps. As part of the process I would like to run a powershell script using the PowerShell Admin Module from devOps pipeline which would grant a list of users access to apps in the solution.

I have been able to run the admin powershell command for Apis to bypass consent as a Service Principal

`Set-AdminPowerAppApisToBypassConsent -EnvironmentName $EnvironmentId -AppName $AppId`

but I am struggling with

`Get-UsersOrGroupsFromGraph -SearchString $EmailAddress`

and

`Set-AdminPowerAppRoleAssignment -PrincipalType "User" -PrincipalObjectId $UserId -RoleName $UserPermission -AppName $AppId -EnvironmentName $EnvironmentId`

Is it not possible to run these commands using a Service Principal account or does the Service Principal need specific permission in order to run this? When I run it as a regular user then it does work. Is there an API that can be used instead which would accomplish the same thing using Service Principal?